# Parameter Add Causing Timeout in DBCommand

Tags: c#, dbcommand

I have a Parameter add function like bellow:

```
public static void AddParameter(DbCommand comm, string ParamName, Object objValue, DbType Paramtype,int paramSize)
{
      //comm.Parameters.Clear();
      DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
      param.ParameterName = ParamName;
      param.DbType = Paramtype;
      param.Size = paramSize;
      param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
      param.Value = objValue;
      comm.Parameters.Add(param);
}
```

Now when do the following:

```
conn.Open();
DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE MemberID=@MemberID";
AddParameter(cmd, "@MemberID", "00000970-b1fd-49ad-89fc-1de066c0076c", DbType.String, 50);
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I get Timeout exception. But if I run the same command Like

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE MemberID='00000970-b1fd-49ad-89fc-1de066c0076c'
```

I get my desired output... Can anybody help me find out where is my problem? `conn` here is a SqlConnection.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `MemberID` in the database? *exactly*? `[n][var]char(max|size)` (which specifically), or `uniqueidentifier` ?

Comment: Are you sure that the type of `MemberID` is VarChar? It seems a Guid to me.. try with : `AddParameter(cmd, "@MemberID", "00000970-b1fd-49ad-89fc-1de066c0076c", DbType.Guid, 0);`

Comment: MemberID is VarChar 50

Comment: Re your "But if I run the same command" - is that "via the same .NET code above" ? or is that "in SQL Server Management Studio" (or whatever other tool)?

Comment: @ Marc Gravell same C# code .... Sorry to all. I made an edit. DbType.String is what I actually used.

Comment: @MehbubeArman hunch: can you try that with `DbType.AnsiString` instead?

Comment: saw that but didn't think that's the problem...

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks.. that really solved my problem... Does String has any problem with varchar?

Comment: @MehbubeArman explained more in an answer; it isn't that "String has any problem with varchar"... more that "String isn't varchar; it is nvarchar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that the column is `varchar(50)`, but you are using `DbType.String`; however, `DbType.String` is `nvarchar(...)` - i.e. unicode. Now, sometimes the server will do the conversion the "right way around" (where "right" here means: the one that doesn't kill performance), but sometimes it will make the alternative choice (for example, it might decide that it can't use the index and do a table scan, or even worse - it might decide to convert every row in turn for the comparison). The best thing to do, then, is to specify the correct data-type in the first place: by using `DbType.AnsiString`. There's nothing "wrong" with either `DbType.String` or `DbType.AnsiString` - so long as they are correctly being used to represent `nvarchar` and `varchar` respectively.